# CustomElementRegistry repeat registration error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, next.js, web-component

I am using the `googlemaps/extended-component-library` to use two web components those being the `APILoader` and the `PlacePicker` components,

When i run my application it throws these errors:

```
'CustomElementRegistry' already has "gmpx-api-loader" defined. 
 ReferenceError: HTMLDivElement is not defined
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Development\Product-Shop\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. create next app
2. install  googlemaps/extended-component-library
3. import APILoader and PlacePicker components from googlemaps/extended-component-library and use them in your application
4. provide APILoader with google api key
5. run your application

From googling i have not found anyone with a similar problem or solution

Comment: There is only one registry, so you can't define a component again, you can add a test ``if(customElements.get("component-name")``

Comment: Can you share example of how you are using `APILoader` and `PlacePicker` in your Next/React components?